# ImportError: cannot import name 'MaxPooling2D'

Tags: python, keras

This is Keras API as **Poling Layer importing** problems,
Below the code,

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPoling2D
from keras.layers import backend as k
```

And now error is,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5eca71dc08e4> in <module>
      3 from keras.models import Sequential
      4 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
----> 5 from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPoling2D
      6 from keras.layers import backend as k
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'MaxPoling2D'
```

**Query:** Need help for installing or setup poling layer in anaconda required version of **Python 3.6.0** .

**Note:** I am using created environment as py36. because it was to difficult to install Tensorflow and keras where I used **Python 3.7.0** . That's why I create new environment where python version is **Python 3.6.0** .

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanks a lot for everyone who try to make a solution and who already post the solutions.
**Finally, I could make a perfect solution and thatis,**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

I should use `tensorflow.keras.layers` Because keras **module** or **API** is available in **Tensrflow 2.0**

***Thanks everyone !***

Answer (score 1):

I see a syntax mistake there

Two `o` in pooling
https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/max_pooling2d/